# File Transfer from Server to Client using java sockets. Error on Server side and File transferred to client is empty

Tags: java, sockets, filenotfoundexception

I have a Client and Server, where in client enters the filename, that filename will be checked on server side under pre-defined path, if the file exists, it will be transferred to client side under a similar pre-defined path. I have two problems :

1) In Server, i am not able to compare the file under given pre-defined path, as it is showing FileNotFoundException (no such file/dir).

2) Even following the above exception, the file is transferred and it is empty.

Here are my Client and Server:

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ft2client
{ 
public static void main(String srgs[])throws IOException
{
Socket s=null;
BufferedReader get=null;
PrintWriter put=null;
try
{ 
s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",8085);
get=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
put=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
}  
catch(Exception e)
{
System.exit(0);
}
                    String u,f;
                    System.out.println("Enter the file name to transfer from server:");
                    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
                    f=dis.readLine();
                    put.println(f);
                    File f1=new File(f);
                    String str = "/home/user/";
                    FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(new File(str,f1.toString()));
                    while((u=get.readLine())!=null)
                    { 
                        byte jj[]=u.getBytes();
                        fs.write(jj);
                    } 
                    fs.close();
                    System.out.println("File received");
                    s.close();
                }      
            }
```

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
     public class ft2server
             { 
                 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
                 { 
                     ServerSocket ss=null;
                     try
                     {  
                         ss=new ServerSocket(8085);
                     }
                     catch(IOException e)
                     { 
                         System.out.println("couldn't listen");
                         System.exit(0);
                     }
                     Socket cs=null;
                     try
                     { 
                         cs=ss.accept();
                         System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     { 
                         System.out.println("Accept failed");
                         System.exit(1);
                     } 
                     PrintWriter put=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
                     BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
                     String s=st.readLine();
                     String str = "/home/user/Desktop/";
                     String path = str + s; 
                     System.out.println("The requested file is path: "+path);
                     System.out.println("The requested file is : "+s);
                     File f=new File(path);
                     if(f.exists())
                     { 
                         BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
                         String line;
                         while((line=d.readLine())!=null)
                         {
                             put.write(line);
                             put.flush();
                         }
                         d.close();
                         System.out.println("File transfered");
                         cs.close();
                         ss.close();
                     }  
                 }  
             }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See with binary data you have change the readers as they are capable of only characters and do not work with byte stream. moreover readline means read till end of line and in binary files ('\n') does not make too much sense. 
This is from documentation of printWriter

`It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.`

What you would want now is to use byte arrays and write them as chunks like this :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
     public class ft2server
         { 

             public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
             { 
                 ServerSocket ss=null;
                 try
                 {  
                     ss=new ServerSocket(8085);
                 }
                 catch(IOException e)
                 { 
                     System.out.println("couldn't listen");
                     System.exit(0);
                 }
                 Socket cs=null;
                 try
                 { 
                     cs=ss.accept();
                     System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
                 }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 { 
                     System.out.println("Accept failed");
                     System.exit(1);
                 } 
                 BufferedOutputStream put=new BufferedOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                 BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
                 String s=st.readLine();
                 String str = "/home/milind/Desktop/";
                 String path = str + s; 
                 System.out.println("The requested file is path: "+path);
                 System.out.println("The requested file is : "+s);
                 File f=new File(path);
                 if(f.isFile())
                 { 
                     FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);


                     byte []buf=new byte[1024];
                     int read;
                     while((read=fis.read(buf,0,1024))!=-1)
                     {
                         put.write(buf,0,read);
                         put.flush();
                     }
                     //d.close();
                     System.out.println("File transfered");
                     cs.close();
                     ss.close();
                 }  
             }  
         }
```

The client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ft2client
{ 
    public static void main(String srgs[])throws IOException
    {
        Socket s=null;
        BufferedInputStream get=null;
        PrintWriter put=null;
        try
        { 
            s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",8085);
            get=new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            put=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

            String f;
            int u;
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to transfer from server:");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            f=dis.readLine();
            put.println(f);
            File f1=new File(f);
            String str = "/home/milind/";
            FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(new File(str,f1.toString()));
            byte jj[]=new byte[1024];
            while((u=get.read(jj,0,1024))!=-1)
            { 
                fs.write(jj,0,u);
            } 
            fs.close();
            System.out.println("File received");
            s.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things are for sure when you are dealing with the socket.

If at the other end you are reading line like `get.readLine();` then from the sender program should have write into socket like this  `put.writeBytes("any string variable"+"\n")` or `put.println("some string variable or literal.")`

you are reading like `get.readLine()`  and you are writing the bytes whatever you are reading from the direct file.

This is my example how I do read,write on the socket when I need pure text to transfer in bytes.

```
Server {
...
soc = echoServer.accept();
out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
out.writeBytes("some text in here \n");
out.flush();

...
}


Client{

...

soc = new Socket("10.210.13.121", 62436);
out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
...  
while(true)
    if(in.available() > 0)
       String str = in.readLine();
... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use f.isFile() instead of f.exisits. It is a known issue.
In server you mistakenly wrote
`BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));`
instead of 
`BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));`
Fixed codes

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
     public class ft2server
         { 
             public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
             { 
                 ServerSocket ss=null;
                 try
                 {  
                     ss=new ServerSocket(8085);
                 }
                 catch(IOException e)
                 { 
                     System.out.println("couldn't listen");
                     System.exit(0);
                 }
                 Socket cs=null;
                 try
                 { 
                     cs=ss.accept();
                     System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
                 }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 { 
                     System.out.println("Accept failed");
                     System.exit(1);
                 } 
                 PrintWriter put=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
                 BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
                 String s=st.readLine();
                 String str = "/home/milind/Desktop/";
                 String path = str + s; 
                 System.out.println("The requested file is path: "+path);
                 System.out.println("The requested file is : "+s);
                 File f=new File(path);
                 if(f.isFile())
                 { 
                     BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                     String line;
                     while((line=d.readLine())!=null)
                     {
                         put.write(line);
                         put.flush();
                     }
                     d.close();
                     System.out.println("File transfered");
                     cs.close();
                     ss.close();
                 }  
             }  
         }
```

Other one

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ft2client
{ 
    public static void main(String srgs[])throws IOException
    {
        Socket s=null;
        BufferedReader get=null;
        PrintWriter put=null;
        try
        { 
            s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",8085);
            get=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            put=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

            String u,f;
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to transfer from server:");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            f=dis.readLine();
            put.println(f);
            File f1=new File(f);
            String str = "/home/milind/";
            FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(new File(str,f1.toString()));
            while((u=get.readLine())!=null)
            { 
                System.out.println(u);
                byte jj[]=u.getBytes();
                fs.write(jj);
            } 
            fs.close();
            System.out.println("File received");
            s.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but when I transferred a zip file, the transferred file size is more & it is showing the following error when I try to open it : _Archive:  /home/user/herb_2.5.7-Stable-Full_Package.zip   13175984   6008
warning [/home/user/herb_2.5.7-Stable-Full_Package.zip]:  571117285 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile (attempting to process anyway) error [/home/user/herb_2.5.7-Stable-Full_Package.zip]:start of central directory not found;zipfile corrupt.(please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)_

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Readers` and `Writers` unless you know that the contents are characters. If you don't, use `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams`. In this case a ZIP file is certainly binary, not character data, so you are bound to corrupt it by using `Readers` and `Writers.`